# WiredTiger .wt file parser (MongoDB)

Tags: parser, mongodb

Is there any tool or piece of code or any library of any language that can help to extract data from .wt file (WiredTiger) of mongodb?

Comment: "parser" is a very vague term. For instance, compilers are also parsers, but I am not sure it is what you want. What should be the output of the tool? Please give an example input and the matching example output. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This Ubuntu open source project compiles .wt files, which means it first parses them:

https://github.com/moneroexamples/compile-wt-ubuntu

Also keep in mind the **.wt** files are stored in very specific format, so they **cannot be converted** to readable text files, even with compression, encryption (if applicable), etc.